# JavaScript sending XmlHttpRequest only works in Debug Console

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, tomcat, servlets

Hello dear commmunity.

I have a problem i cannot seem to solve. 
Let me explain what i try to do.

I have a simple JSF-Site with a select file dialog and a submit button.
When a user selects a file and clicks the submit button this file shall be send to a servlet on my server, where it is saved locally and a db entry shall be created that points to the location of the file.
Sounds simple right?
Here is my solution so far:

The JavaScript:

```
function postUploadedFile() {
    var servlet = "UploadImageToServer";
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('filedataDecoded');
    var fileTypeElement = document.getElementById('filedataType');
    var encodedFile = inputElement.textContent;
    var fileType = fileTypeElement.textContent;
    inputElement.textContent = "";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/TestJSF/" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4)) {
              // handle callback
              console.log("done");
        }
     }
    xmlhttp.send(encodedFile);
    console.log();
}
```

My Servlet:

```
public class UploadImageToServer extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadImageToServer.class);

    private String dbUser = "xxxx";

    private String dbPw = "xxxx";

    public UploadImageToServer() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        Connection con = null;
        InputStream fileDataStream = request.getInputStream();
        int fileContentLength = request.getContentLength();
        String fileType = (request.getParameter("fileType")).split("\\.")[1];
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] fileDataBytes64 = new byte[fileContentLength];
        byte[] bufferTemp = new byte[1024];
        int nRead;
        while ((nRead = fileDataStream.read(bufferTemp, 0, bufferTemp.length)) != -1) {
          buffer.write(bufferTemp, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        String tempString = buffer.toString();
        String base64String = tempString.split("base64,")[1];
        System.out.println("test");
        Double newRandom = (double) -1;
        while(newRandom < 5000 || newRandom > 1000000) {
            newRandom = Math.random() * 10000;
        }
        String valueOf = String.valueOf((newRandom));
        String fileName = (valueOf.split("\\."))[0] + "." + fileType;
        File tempFile = new File("C:\\storage\\" + fileName);
        byte[] fileDataDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
        tempFile.getParentFile().mkdir();
        tempFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream foS = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        foS.write(fileDataDecoded);
        foS.close();
        String driver = PossibleDbDriver.MYSQL.getIdentifier();
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
            logger.error("Error - no valid Driver-Class specified - [" + driver + "]");
            logger.error("Message - [" + e2.getMessage() + "]");
        }
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imagetest";
        try {
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUser,dbPw);
            stm = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO images (image_name,image_path,image_likes,image_dislikes,image_timestamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            stm.setString(1, tempFile.getName());
            stm.setString(2, tempFile.getPath());
            stm.setDouble(3, 0);
            stm.setDouble(4, 0);
            stm.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            stm.execute();
         } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error - Connection could not be established.");
                logger.error("Message - [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
         } 
    }
}
```

Servlet Mapping:

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UploadImageToServer</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadImageToServer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mk.imageboard.servlets.UploadImageToServer</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadImageToServer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadImageToServer</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The file data comes from another script that reads it as a Base64-String and writes it to the TextArea-Element 'filedataDecoded' (Just to clarify this). 
The Application Server is Tomcat 6.0.36 and the JSF implementation is MyFaces 2.1.13. 
Everything runs on the same machine(my computer).

Now to my actual problem...
When i let Tomcat run in normal mode and access my site and try to upload a file, the XmlHttpRequest is not send. However when i do the same thing with opened JavaScript Console in Chrome and set breakpoints to:

```
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/TestJSF/" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4)) {
                      // handle callback
                      console.log("done");
                }
             }
            xmlhttp.send(encodedFile);
```

and step through the script, the request is send and the servlet works fine.
I searched stackoverflow for a solution but couldn't find any. Same with the internet. It's such a weird error and i can't understand why it does not work.
If someone could help me out i would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: Did you try with any other browser?

Comment: Yes. I tried Firefox too. The same problem. In debug console with the breakpoints set it works, without and without console it doesn't. (I left IE out)

Comment: then, it's something serious!

Comment: I wonder if there is some sort of asynchronous aspect to reading the file maybe? Try wrapping the body of the `postUploadedFile` method in a try-catch block, and then logging the resulting error object to `console.error(...)`

Comment: i enclosed my code in a try-catch block, but no error is thrown. I also set a breakpoint to console.log(error) line, but it isn't called.
I don't think it is a problem with reading the file. The data is present when i press the submit button. The data is read via another button that fills the text-area-elements. So the `postUploadFile`only access allready present data.

Comment: Did you try using relative path instead of absolute path ? Show Below:
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/TestJSF/" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);

Comment: try to create and using a new xmlhttp object. not the one that you are using for all ajax connections.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, i tried:
the approach of @TugrulAsik and it throws: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/TestJSF/UploadImageToServer?fileType=foto.jpg. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

Also @AmirNoori i allways create a new Object. I never use the same and it is allways locale in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I have found the solution or the cause of the problem.

Somehow the `<h:form>...</h:form>` surrounding the actual submit button firing the javascript prevented the sending of the request, but as to why it does, I don't know. I deleted the form and it works now correctly.

Does someone have a guess on why this caused the problem? I would really like to know.

But thanks anyway guys. Have a happy new year :)

With kind regards

Chris

EDIT: The missing HTML-Snipped of my site. Sorry I should have added it, my bad!

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <!-- Testbereich -->
            <fieldset>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" onchange=""/>
                <input type="submit" value="Verschluesseln" onclick="loadUploadedFile();"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <div> Uploaddaten nicht verschluesselt:</div>
                <h:inputTextarea id="filedataType" styleClass="textareaOutput" disabled="true"/>
                <h:inputTextarea id="filedataDecoded" styleClass="textareaOutput" disabled="true"/>
            </fieldset>
            <!-- <h:form id="uploadForm"> -->
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="submit" onclick="postUploadedFile();"/>
                </fieldset>
            <!-- </h:form> -->
    </ui:define>
```

To clarify `loadUploadedFile()` is the javascript that reads the file and returns the Base64 String.

Comment: Please add the HTML so we can take a look. I'm guessing you are using a HTML submit button with an onclick? If that is the case, the submit button is going to submit the form which may not leave enough time to run your JS from the onclick event. You could try changing the submit to a <button> or simply removing the form like you did should be fine (again, not having seen the HTML).

Comment: Thanks @pherris I think that this is the logical cause. In fact the page reloads and I could have guessed this myself. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use relative path instead of absolute path.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "TestJSF/" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);
```

or

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);
```

Update:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

doPost(request,response);
    }
```

---

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "TestJSF/" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);
```

or

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work. It seems as if the servlet cannot be accessed this way.
Should it be? Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to know which path you are working on . It may be "/TestJSF/" or "/". It's  related to your working path. And be sure about your parameter values are true.

Comment: Sadly still not working:
`xmlhttp.open("POST", "/TestJSF/" + servlet + "?fileType="+fileType , true);`
Works but still only in the debug console. 
The approach with GET -> redirect to post-method does not work(Not even with debug console).
The parameter values are set, or what did you mean with "And be sure about your parameter values are true."